# Why do I have NullPointerException in build() while sending notification in Service?

Tags: android, service, notifications

I would like to send notifications in a Service. However, when I try to use the following code to send a notification, it just cause a `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.List android.os.IUserManager.getProfiles(int, boolean)' on a null object reference`.

My problem is that I can use the following code to create a notification and notification manager then send it in my **Activity**. But **not** in my **Service**. Is there some special case while using Service? And I've tested that `this` is not null in `NotificationCompat.Builder(this)`.

I suppose the exception may be caused by application context in `build()` while creating a `NotificationCompat`?

Following is the entire class of my service.

```
package com.example.yang.backservice;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyBackService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("onBind", "ServiceDemo onBind");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d("onCreate", "ServiceDemo onCreate");
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("onStartCommand", "ServiceDemo onStartCommand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat
                .Builder(this)
                .setTicker("Ticker")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText("Text")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

And I start the service by using

```
Intent myBgService = new Intent(this, MyBackService.class);
startService(myBgService);
```

in my main activity.

And I have

```
<service
    android:name=".MyBackService"
    android:exported="false"
    android:isolatedProcess="true" />
```

in my AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @TimCastelijns I think my problem is unique. Because in that question. My problem is Why do I have NullPointerException which creating notification. The problem that you pointed out is What is a NullPointerException.

Comment: 1) `this` is never null 2) *Is there some special case while using Service?* no it works when I try it with your code in a service

Comment: @ZhipengYANG fair enough, it's not as obvious of an NPE as I thought. Retracted my vote

Comment: @TimCastelijns 1) Well, I know `this` is never null. But I cannot figure out why it throws an NPE. 2) I edited and gave the entire service. Plz read it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the solution is pretty simple.
Just remove `android:isolatedProcess="true"` in **AndroidManifest.xml**.

I saw a tutorial which said that if we want to create a background service, we have to add `android:isolatedProcess="true"` in our **AndroidManifest.xml**. And he was wrong. We can simply return `START_STICKY` in our `public int onStartCommand(...)`.

According to the official document [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#isolated), if `android:isolatedProcess` is set to true, Android will isolate it from the rest of the system. So it couldn't send notifications.